# What happens to any adjacently allocated variables in memory in a overflow case

Tags: function, memory, cs50

While I was looking at CS50 Test Spring 2017, I bumped into that question:

http://cdn.cs50.net/2017/spring/test/bleep.html

The indicated answer for the first question on the link (Bleep) is as following:

> Because only 4 bytes are allocated for word, 5-letter words like puppy
>   and 6-letter words like kitten **will overflow that buffer, with
>   their fifth letters' (non-zero) ASCII codes ending up in the memory
>   allocated for bleep**. The value of bleep will thus be non-zero (i.e.,
>   not false), and so bleep will effectively be true, in which case those
>   words are bleep.

I didn't get why overflow leads to a non-zero bleep value. I am aware of the concept of memory leak. But I guess, don't know what is hindered by overflowing of that buffer.

If somebody explains detaily or share some source respect this topic, would much appreciated.

Comment: Anything at all can happen—just to the process (assuming the program is running under a system with process isolation) and to external systems it can affect. The linked question gives a prototypical memory layout but there is no guarantee that that's the layout. Just don't do that.

Comment: Memory leak refers to something else: "owning" a block of memory and losing track of where it is. It doesn't apply to the "automatic" variables `word` and `bleep`. The compiler takes care of generating code to acquire and release them within the well-defined flow of the function.

Comment: So what can be done for retrieving a memory that has already leaked. I mean how any cluster of memory that we lost track of can be freed ?

Comment: (If you want to respond, please post another question.) It doesn't really matter until the process runs out of address space (or any part of it that it has sectioned off like heap, stack, etc) or the system runs out page file space, or the system has to thrash with page faults (which it wouldn't if the leaked memory is in blocks that can fall out of use). Keep in mind that RAM is effectively just a cache for virtual memory (paging files on disk). The only recovery is to exit: cleanly, programmatically, or by crashing, or by the user (or, potentially, a supervisory program) killing the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the image in the question shows, the memory layout looks like this:

```
xxxx0
    ^- bleep
```

`xxxx` is the memory reserved for `word` and `0` is reserved for `bleep`.

If you put a 3-letter word in `word` the memory looks like this:

```
dog00
    ^- bleep
```

The second to last zero is the terminator for the string. No overflow, no problems.

If you have a five-letter word, the space reserved for `bleep` is overwritten when `word` overflows.

```
puppy0
    ^- bleep
```

There wasn't enough space for the word "puppy" so it overflowed and overwrote the value of `bleep`. Now the value of `bleep` is the ASCII value of 'y' (121) which is non-zero and `bleep` has changed from false to true.

Comment: Very well ELI5 explanation thank you! I haven't known that any number other than 0 and 1 also considered as true(1).